# Camera2 api preview is not same with capture

Tags: android, android-camera2

I am using [camera2Basic example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic) and I fixed exposure time, iso, white balance and etc.

```
mPreviewBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);

//mPreviewBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.LENS_FOCUS_DISTANCE, DEFAULT_FOCUS_DISTANCE);

mPreviewBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AE_MODE_OFF);

mPreviewBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.NOISE_REDUCTION_MODE, CameraMetadata.NOISE_REDUCTION_MODE_FAST);
mPreviewBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.EDGE_MODE, CameraMetadata.EDGE_MODE_FAST);
mPreviewBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_PRECAPTURE_TRIGGER, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_PRECAPTURE_TRIGGER_CANCEL);

mPreviewBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AWB_MODE, wbMode);
mPreviewBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AWB_LOCK, wbLock);

mPreviewBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SENSOR_SENSITIVITY, isoValue);
mPreviewBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME, exposureValue);
```

I am taking several `photos` by rotating my phone for stitching.
While taking photos the `preview looks` fine, but captured results are totally different in terms of brightness

When I checked the images exif data, they have same exposure time and iso (not on Nexus)

I don't know what I am missing.
Any suggestion why it is happening? Thank you

Comment: what do you mean by different? if it rotates photos or something else?

Comment: photos rotation is fine. one photo is brighter, other one is darker. I cannot stitch if they are not similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was not using `session.setRepeatingRequest()` and `session.capture()` properly. Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42158047/5344661)